# Print the powershell Windows multiple events in Single email-Event ID-4726

Tags: powershell, events, active-directory

Looking for help on regarding PowerShell event printing the output windows log event into email body message.
Here my below PowerShell code to get email alert when user gets deleted. It's working when single user gets deleted, its get email trigger with below attached format. But When multiple user getting  deleted in same time, am I getting an error(ERROR1). How do I get when users get deleted multiple events occurred, event should capture for multiple events print into separate email in each event or same email ??

ERROR1

```
Cannot convert value "System.Object[]" to type "System.Xml.XmlDocument". Error: "This document already has a 'DocumentElement' node."
At line:5 char:11
+           $xmlEventResult = [xml]$EventResult
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastToXmlDocument
 
Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
At line:8 char:33
+           $EventDate = Get-Date $EventDate -format ('MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
+                                 ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterBindingFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

PowerShell's script :

```
Function EventID-To-HTML($ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME)
         {
          $EventResult = wevtutil qe Security /rd:true /c:6 /f:renderedxml /q:"*[System[(EventID=4726)]]"
   if ($EventResult -eq $null){exit}
          $xmlEventResult = [xml]$EventResult

          $EventDate = $xmlEventResult.Event.System.TimeCreated.SystemTime
          $EventDate = Get-Date $EventDate -format ('MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss')
         
          $htmlStart = "<HTML>
                          <HEAD>
                            <style>
                              body {background-color:rgb(238, 238, 238);}
                              body, table, td, th {font-family:Calibri; color:Black; Font-Size:11pt}
                                               th {font-weight:bold; background-color:rgb(78, 227, 48);}
                                               td {background-color:rgb(255, 190, 0);}
                            </style>
                          </HEAD>
                        <BODY><div align=center>
                        <h2><b><br><br>Security Alert: <span Style='font-style:normal; color:Blue'>A user account was deleted</span></b></h2>
                        <p><b><br>This event occurred at: <span Style='font-style:italic; color:Blue'>$EventDate on $ComputerName</span></b></p>"
          $htmlEnd = ''
          $htmlStart

          $xmlEventResult.Event.EventData.Data | Select-Object Name, @{Label = "Value"; Expression={$_."#Text"}} | Group-Object -Property __Class |
          ForEach-Object {$_.Group | Select-Object -Property * | ConvertTo-HTML -Body ('' -f "$_.Name")}
         
          $htmlStart = ''
         
          $htmlStart = $htmlStart + "<br><i><span Style='color:red'>This report has been generated by software</i> <br><i>Please DO NOT reply.</i></div>"
          $htmlStart
         
          $htmlEnd = ''
          $htmlEnd
         }

# ======================
# Sending Email Section
# ======================

$strFrom = "ad1@ad-local.local"
$strTo = "stackover@example.com"
$strSubject = "*** Event Listener - User Deleted ***"
$strSMTPServer = "smtp.example.com"

$objEmailMessage = New-Object system.net.mail.mailmessage
$objEmailMessage.From = ($strFrom)
$objEmailMessage.To.Add($strTo)
$objEmailMessage.Subject = $strSubject
$objEmailMessage.IsBodyHTML = $true
$objEmailMessage.Body = EventID-To-HTML 

$objSMTP = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($strSMTPServer)
$objSMTP.Send($objEmailMessage)
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like you need to loop over `$EventResult`. Do you want a separate email for each deleted user of are you planning on creating an email where you can list more deleted users?

Comment: oh, ok. 
 yes, Exactly, separate email for each deleted user or if it prints single email no problem